# Wordpress : function create new post after creating a new user

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a new post (of a custom post type) just after creating a new user (editor only).
I think i have to use a hook like this :

```
do_action('user_register', $user_id);
add_action ('user_register', "create_post");
function create_post()
{
// Create the post
}
```

But i don't know how to create the post in this function.
And I have some custom fields in the new user form...

Thanks
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

Try to use arguments with the add_action here is the simple example

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_post', 10, 1 );

function create_post( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        ..... your code  here

}
```

and for the inert post use this function in given link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Answer (score 0):

From the wordpress codex [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

You can do code like this

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    //Here you can update user information after they registered
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
    }

}
```

To insert post after user registered try the extended code:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    //Here you can update user information after they registered
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
    }

    // Here you can insert new post for registered users
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Title',
        'post_content' => 'some content',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => $user_id, //If to assign post to the currently registered user otherwise put 1
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $_post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
    if ($_post_id) {
        return 'post inserted';
    }
}
```

[update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) lets you update user other information after they registered
[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) lets you insert posts programatically